# To stop ClickJacking, which one is more secure? breaking out of iframe vs X-Frame-Options to Deny or Same Origin

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, clickjacking

To prevent clickjacking from happenning for your website, I have noticed several different methods. Some use javascript to have your website break out of iframe, the other soltution is to set the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header to DENY or SAMEORIGIN. 
Which one of the 2 method I mentioned do you think is more secure? Here is a sample page I am using to test clickjacking.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<H1>Clickjacking Test</H1>
<IFRAME SRC="http://www.google.com/" HEIGHT="500" WIDTH="500"></IFRAME>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

With iframe break code you will see Firefox and Safari will be slow to get out of Iframe, meaning you will see Clickjacking test and then it will break out of that iframe and show the original website. With IE and Chrome it is fast that not noticeable. 
But with X-Frame-Optiions solution you simply do not see your website at all. It will be blocked. Like with google in the above example. So my questions is which one of the solution better? Blocking it completely or breaking out of iframe(slow in 2 browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, setting `X-Frame-Options (XFO)` rules works much better than breaking out of iframes. When it comes to rules, it really depends on if you absolutely have to use iframes. If you can remove iframes from your website completely, using the DENY rule would be best; however, if you still have iframes in your site, use the SAMEORIGIN rules.

The differences between the available rules are outlined below ([quoted from IETF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gondrom-frame-options-00)):

1. **DENY**
   A browser receiving content with this header MUST NOT display
   this content in any frame.
2. **SAMEORIGIN**
   A browser receiving content with this header MUST NOT display
   this content in any frame from a page of different origin than
   the content itself.
   If a browser or plugin can not reliably determine whether the
   origin of the content and the frame have the same origin, this
   MUST be treated as "DENY".
   [TBD]current implementations do not display if the origin of
   the top-level-browsing-context is different than the origin of
   the page containing the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header.
3. **ALLOW-FROM**  (followed by a URI of trusted origins)
   A browser receiving content with this header MUST NOT display
   this content in any frame from a page of different origin than
   the listed origin.  While this can expose the page to risks by
   the trusted origin, in some cases it may be necessary to use
   content from other domains.
   For example: X-FRAME-OPTIONS: ALLOW-FROM
   https://www.domain.com/

I would also suggest reading, [Clickjack attack – the hidden threat right in front of you](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/clickjack-attack-hidden-threat-right-in.html) by Troy Hunt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I read Troy Hunt's article and it kinda aligns with what OWASP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet suggests. OWASP also suggested that frame buster solutions can introduce XSS. So therefore I think the safer solution would be XFO. Now older versions of browsers I beleive does not support XFO and the only solution for older browser maybe frame busters. I wonder what happens when use both XFO and Framebusters.

Comment: @DoodleKana You can use a belt and braces approach - add the header as well as frame busting script. The header will be read and block the frame load before the script is made available to the browser, so this approach will be backwards compatible. It doesn't say the scripts can introduce XSS... OWASP mentions that a frame busting script can be disabled using IE8 and Chrome's XSS filter by altering the IFrame src, but since these browsers support XFO this should not present a problem.

Comment: I read the clickjacking_defence_cheat_sheet and I was intrigue by the solution owasp is suggesting in the portion "Best-for-now Legacy Browser Frame Breaking Script". In the propose solution, body is hidden by default. It is displayed only using javascript if certain criteria is met. I wonder, does the techinique does not affect site ranking like google ranking or bing?

Comment: I doubt Google SE would considers the contents of iframes.

Answer (score 3):

`X-Frame-Options` is the ‘proper’ solution, that solves the problem by completely blocking framing. It is the better method, but there are still browsers out that that don't support it (most notably IE<8). So to cover those cases you need a JavaScript solution **as well**.

There are two problems with JavaScript framebusters:

Firstly: most of them try to ‘break out’ of the frame, replacing the main window with their document. However the attacker document in the parent window can easily resist being navigated and though there are workarounds, they can [always themselves be circumvented][Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)). If your script detects you have been framed, the better solution from a security point of view is to make the whole page unusable, for example by settings `document.body.innerHTML` to an error message.

The parent-navigation approach happens because framebusters originated as a means for webmasters to escape from unwanted framing from sites like search engines. It wasn't a security issue for them, and they didn't want to lose any traffic by barring access, so they chose a solution that doesn't provide security.

Secondly: framebusters can be prevented from running, by running the frame in an iframe with IE's [`security="restricted"` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534622(v=vs.85).aspx), or through [false-positive attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052195/18936) on XSS filters, or just because the user has JS turned off. You can get around this by having the page *only* work when JavaScript is enabled, but that has obvious negative accessibility impact.