# Encoding XSS attack (</script><svg/onload=alert(window.location.href)>) not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, xss, sanitization

when I am executing below URL in IE, I am getting alert message:

```
URL : https://test.com/test?path=valid</script><svg/onload=alert(window.location.href)>
```

but same thing is working fine in chrome (no alert).

For chrome, when I am checking dev tools, URL is coming in encoded format. How to enforce encoding in IE and prevent XSS attack.

Comment: Yes, when I hit this URL in IE address bar, alert happens. Also, my security team has raised this concern as part of possible xss attack. Still we need to handle this case. Any ideas on how to remove/encode this.

Comment: That all depends on what you do with the `?path` query_param.

Comment: But how is this not xss attack?

Comment: There is no Cross-Site Scripting. That's just execution of arbitrary code, which could be done as easily from the console, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't fix it,  if your scripts can be defeated by such a simple input, you need to fix it for sure. Once again, we need to see what you do with `?path` to give you better advices, but that sounds like *el.innerHTML = unsafe_input*, which is pretty bad anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the url, you could encode the url using the [encodeURI() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).

To prevent XSS attack, you could try to enable the IE browser XSS filter, please open the IE Internet Settings, on the security Internet zone click the "Custom level...", then enable the XSS filter. More detail about XSS filter, please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051632/ie8-xss-filter-what-does-it-really-do).

[image]